# If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the angles of a triangle then find the value of $\Delta$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, determinant, triangles

I'll state the question from my book below:

> If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the angles of a triangle, then find the determinant value of
>   $$\Delta = \begin{vmatrix}\sin^2A & \cot A & 1 \\ \sin^2B & \cot B & 1 \\ \sin^2C & \cot C & 1\end{vmatrix}.$$

Here's how I tried solving the problem:

$\Delta = \begin{vmatrix}\sin^2A & \cot A & 1 \\ \sin^2B & \cot B & 1 \\ \sin^2C & \cot C & 1\end{vmatrix}$

$R_2 \to R_2 - R_1$

$R_3 \to R_3 -R_1$

$= \begin{vmatrix}\sin^2A & \cot A & 1 \\ \sin^2B-\sin^2A & \cot B-\cot A & 0 \\ \sin^2C-\sin^2A & \cot C-\cot A & 0\end{vmatrix}$

Expanding the determinant along $C_3$

\begin{align}
&= (\sin^2B-\sin^2A)(\cot C-\cot A)-(\cot B-\cot A)(\sin^2C-\sin^2A)  \\
&= \sin(B+A) \sin(B-A) \left[\frac {\cos C}{\sin C} - \frac {\cos A}{\sin A}\right] - \left[\frac {\cos B}{\sin B} - \frac {\cos A}{\sin A}\right]\sin(C+A) \sin(C-A)  \\
&= \frac {\sin(B+A) \sin(B-A) \sin(A-C)} {\cos A \cos C} - \frac {\sin(A-B) \sin(C+A) \sin(C-A)} {\cos A \cos C}  \\
&= \frac {\sin(B-A) \sin (A-C)} {\cos A} \left[\frac {\sin(A+B)} {\cos C} - \frac {\sin(A+C)} {\cos B}\right]  \\
&= \frac {\sin(B-A) \sin (A-C)} {\cos A} \left[\frac {\sin C} {\cos C} - \frac {\sin B} {\cos B}\right]  \\
&= \frac {\sin(B-A) \sin (A-C) \sin (C-B)} {\cos A \cos B \cos C}
\end{align}

I tried solving further but the expression just got complicated. I don't even know if the work I've done above is helpful. My textbook gives the answer as $0$. I don't have any clue about getting the answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F=\begin{vmatrix}  \sin^2B-\sin^2A & \cot B-\cot A   \\ \sin^2C-\sin^2A & \cot C-\cot A  \end{vmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{vmatrix}  \sin^2B-\sin^2A & -\dfrac{\sin(B-A)}{\sin A\sin B}   \\ \sin^2C-\sin^2A & -\dfrac{\sin(C-A)}{\sin C\sin A}  \end{vmatrix}$$

$$=\dfrac1{\sin B\sin^2A\sin C}\begin{vmatrix}\sin(B-A)\sin(B+A)\sin B\sin A&-\sin(B-A)\\ \sin(C-A)\sin(C+A)\sin C\sin A&-\sin(C-A)\end{vmatrix}$$

Using $A+B+C=\pi,\sin(B+A)=\sin C$ etc.,

$$F=\dfrac{\sin A\sin B\sin C}{\sin^2A\sin B\sin C}\begin{vmatrix}\sin(B-A)&-\sin(B-A)\\\sin(C-A)&-\sin(C-A)\end{vmatrix}=?$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understood everything other than how you got to the expression $=\dfrac1{\cos B\cos^2A\cos C}\begin{vmatrix}\sin(B-A)\sin(B+A)\sin B\sin A&-\sin(B-A)\\ \sin(C-A)\sin(C+A)\sin C\sin A&-\sin(C-A)\end{vmatrix}$ from the previous one.

Comment: @SamInuyashaANMF, Please find the rectified answer

Answer (score 1):

In the standard notation we obtain:
$$\Delta=\sum_{cyc}\sin^2\alpha(\cot\beta-\cot\gamma)=\sum_{cyc}\frac{4S^2}{b^2c^2}\left(\frac{\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}}{\frac{2S}{ac}}-\frac{\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}}{\frac{2S}{ab}}\right)=$$
$$=S\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2-a^2-b^2+c^2}{b^2c^2}=2S\sum_{cyc}\frac{c^2-b^2}{b^2c^2}=2S\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{b^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}\right)=0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm sorry, I'm probably not aware of the standard notation you are talking of. But how do you get $\sin A = \frac {2S} {bc}$? Which formula did you use?

Answer (score 1):

By Euler's theorem $O,G,H$ are collinear. By considering their trilinear coordinates it follows that
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}\cos(A) & \cos(B) & \cos(C) \\ \frac{1}{\sin A}&\frac{1}{\sin B}&\frac{1}{\sin C}\\ \frac{1}{\cos A}&\frac{1}{\cos B}&\frac{1}{\cos C}\end{pmatrix}=0$$
and by multiplying the first column by $\cos(A)$, the second column by $\cos(B)$ and the third column by $\cos(C)$ we get that
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}\cos^2(A) & \cos^2(B) & \cos^2(C) \\ \cot(A)&\cot(B)&\cot(C)\\ 1&1&1\end{pmatrix}=0$$
and by replacing the first row with the difference between the third row and the first row
$$ \det\begin{pmatrix}\sin^2(A) & \sin^2(B) & \sin^2(C) \\ \cot(A)&\cot(B)&\cot(C)\\ 1&1&1\end{pmatrix}=0$$
readily follows. One may also notice that if $\theta\in\{A,B,C\}$ then
$$ 8R^2\cdot \sin^2\theta + 4[ABC]\cdot\cot\theta -(a^2+b^2+c^2)\cdot 1 = 0 $$
hence the nullspace of the given matrix has dimension $\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You solved it all right , just took cosA.cos C in denominator instead of sinA.SinC

$\Delta = \begin{vmatrix}\sin^2A & \cot A & 1 \\ \sin^2B & \cot B & 1 \\ \sin^2C & \cot C & 1\end{vmatrix}$

$R_2 \to R_2 - R_1$

$R_3 \to R_3 -R_1$

$= \begin{vmatrix}\sin^2A & \cot A & 1 \\ \sin^2B-\sin^2A & \cot B-\cot A & 0 \\ \sin^2C-\sin^2A & \cot C-\cot A & 0\end{vmatrix}$

Expanding the determinant along $C_3$

$= (\sin^2B-\sin^2A)(\cot C-\cot A)-(\cot B-\cot A)(\sin^2C-\sin^2A)$

$= \sin(B+A) \sin(B-A)[\frac {\cos C}{\sin C} - \frac {\cos A}{\sin A}] - [\frac {\cos B}{\sin B} - \frac {\cos A}{\sin A}]\sin(C+A) \sin(C-A)$

$= \frac {\sin(B+A) \sin(B-A) \sin(A-C)} {\sinA \sinc C} - \frac {\sin(A-B) \sin(C+A) \sin(C-A)} {\sinA \sin C}$

$= \frac {\sin(B-A) \sin (A-C)} {\sin A} [\frac {\sin(A+B)} {\sin C} - \frac {\sin(A+C)} {\sin B}]$

$= \frac {\sin(B-A) \sin (A-C)} {\sin A} [\frac {\sin C} {\sin C} - \frac {\sin B} {\sin B}]$

$= \frac {\sin(B-A) \sin (A-C) \sin (A)} [\{0}]$

Answer (score 0):

A hint, as requested:

What you've done looks pretty good; I haven't checked every bit of the algebra, but the symmetry of the result makes me think that you've probably done it right.

What you have *not* done is use the important fact given at the start: that $A, B,$ and $C$ are the angles of a triangle (hence they sum to $\pi$). I don't see right away how to use that fact, but it's clearly important.

Comment: Umm, John, isn’t $\cot(\pi/2)=0$?

Comment: Ooops. More coffee needed. I'll edit. :)

Comment: I used that fact as well when I got $sin (A+B) = \sin C$ and $sin (A+C) = sin B$.